# insert a data and get back ID in spring boot JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hi i am trying to insert a record in Mysql and get the ID of the inserted user in Spring boot JPA. i am getting following error. i have seen couple of questions like this but there they provided answer as USE JDBC Template for these kind of output. is it not possible to do it??. or this is related to some other issue.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String createsignup(@RequestParam String name,@RequestParam String email,@RequestParam String password, ModelMap model) {
     int userid = 0;
     User user  = new User(name,email);
     userrepository.save(user);
     userid = user.getId();
     Authentication auth = new Authentication(email,password,userid);
     authrepository.save(auth);
     model.put("remember_token", auth.getRemember_token());
     return "redirect:/profile";
 }
```

Model

```
  @Entity
```

public class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String location;

public User() {

}
}
```

Error

```
      018-01-31 23:45:32.890  INFO 2512 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 7 ms
      Hibernate: insert into user (email, location, name) values (?, ?, ?)
      Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
2018-01-31 23:45:41.783 ERROR 2512 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]  o.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure   : could not read a hi value

    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table  'blog.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

**UPDATE**

application properties

```
 spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
 spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
 logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO

 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
 spring.jpa.show-sql = true
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog
 spring.datasource.username=pranava
 spring.datasource.password=**********
```

This the message from server log

```
2018-02-01 22:21:29.691  INFO 5648 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
2018-02-01 22:21:29.693  INFO 5648 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}

 2018-02-01 22:21:29.928  INFO 5648 --- [  restartedMain]               org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

2018-02

Comment: try to use `userrepository.flush();` after `userrepository.save(user);` and before `userid = user.getId();`

Comment: `Table  'blog.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist` seems like the problem is here.. Have you configured the tables autocreation, for example `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` in application.properties? Or you can create this sequence table by hand.

Comment: @BogdanOros in table ID column is autoincrement and primary key

Comment: @YCF_L not working :(

Comment: @Pranavadurai, check the error message please or paste a new one, if that has changed.

Comment: @BogdanOros Same error message no change

Comment: As you can see in error, hibernate tries to fetch that ID from the database from sequence table, so the problem can be with incorrect dialect (read @Izagkaretos answer)

Comment: @BogdanOros i have tried that also no same error

Comment: @BogdanOros. i have updated the question with appliation properties and one log i noticed recently please see that also

Comment: Actually you have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`, could you try to set it to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`? It will create all metatables (and yours for entities) by itself

Comment: @BogdanOros. it worked. actually what is the difference in this ??. when auto = none will work ??

Comment: if you use `auto = none`, you need to create all necessary tables (and metatables like this) by yourself. With `ddl-auto=update|create|create-drop` hibernate will create tables on startup for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of search and try i found that User Table is default table in Postgresql. that's why it did not allowed. i have changed the table name and it worked. is there any other way is there to reuse it ?.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have specified the correct dialect for hibernate and MySQL. It seems that value for identity column can't be set correctly.

For instance, if you use Spring Boot, check your application properties for something like:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Or if you use Spring MVC without Spring Boot, that you have:

```
hibernateJpa.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
```

in `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` configuration.

Comment: Hi i have tried by adding this an still no change in error.i have updated the question with application properties and log from server saying that hibernate.properties not found.i spring boot how to solve this. .